# awk one liner to create third column field from two columns

Tags: awk

Looking for a awk one liner create a new third field based on the second field.

starting data:

```
column1,test.columna
column2,test1.columnb
column3,test2.columnc
```

end data where test.columna (2nd field) is now "columnatest" (for the first row) in a new third field separated by ",".

```
column1,test.columna,columnatest
column2,test1.columnb,columnbtest1
column3,test2.columnc,columnctest2
```

getting the third column by itself easy enough :

```
awk -F, '{print $2}' a | awk -F. '{print $2$1}'

columnatest
columnbtest1
columnctest2
```

Having trouble combining all three fields.

Comment: If we elaborate your idea it becomes something like this: awk -F'[,.]' '{print $0,$2$1}' OFS="," file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {split($2,f,/\./); print $0, f[2] f[1]}' file
column1,test.columna,columnatest
column2,test1.columnb,columnbtest1
column3,test2.columnc,columnctest2
```

Comment: Ok, but why you don't play with the FS? *(ie: `-F[.,]`)* Isn't it shorter?

Comment: Yeah that'd be fine too, you'd just have to be sure to use `$NF` and `$(NF-1)` in case `column1`, etc. contains `.`s (`awk 'BEGIN{FS="[.,]"; OFS=","} {print $0, $NF $(NF-1)}' file`) and make sure not to modify any field if this becomes part of a larger script.

Comment: My idea was to only write: `awk -F[.,] '{print $0","$NF$1}'` *(with the last separator hardcoded)*

Comment: IMHO whether you hard-code `","` or set OFS doesn't matter much. ITYM `$(NF-1)`, though, not `$1`. Brevity isn't a goal in itself so as long as the code's concise and efficient, whatever....

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo '
column1,test.columna
column2,test1.columnb
column3,test2.columnc' |
```

---

```
mawk -F, 'sub("$",FS substr($2 $2, 1 + index($2, "."), length($2)-1))'
```

---

```
column1,test.columna,columnatest
column2,test1.columnb,columnbtest1
column3,test2.columnc,columnctest2
```